# Получить данные из базы сгрупированные по месяцу

Tags: php, sql, база-данных

Есть таблица событий с датами в формате TIMESTAMP *(например 2016-02-10 19:17:01)*.
  Возможно ли получить выборку значений, сгруппированных по месяцам создания? Т.е. на выходе получить массив с вложенными массивами, в которых будут события относящиеся к конкретному месяцу конкретного года.
Мне необходимо реализовать архив событий с выводом месяца и года создания (последние 6 месяцев публикации данных). Вот сломал голову, как это сделать грамотно, избегая кучи циклов с условиями и переборов огромного количества значений базы.

Comment: Вы можете дать `group by extract(year_month from date_field)` ну а вложенные массивы полюбому делать средствами php

Answer (score 3):

> избегая переборов огромного количества значений базы.

чтобы избежать перебора огромного количества значений, надо запрашивать у БД только те данные, которые требуется показать. В данном случае необходимо ограничить выборку последними шестью месяцами. Это делается средствами SQL.

> избегая кучи циклов с условиями

Следует понимать, что цикла избежать в любом случае не удастся. Невозможно получить данные из БД в массив без цикла.

Тем не менее, никакой "кучи" циклов здесь не нужно - нужен всего один цикл, который считывает данные из БД и распихивает их по массивам. Один цикл с одним условием - ничего сложного.

> как это сделать грамотно

Грамотно будет воспользоваться PDO и одной из его волшебных констант, а именно - [PDO::FETCH_GROUP](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo/fetch#best), для чего первой колонкой надо будет выбрать значение, содержащее конкретный месяц конкретного года. В этом случае писать цикл самому не придется, PDO выполнит его сам. Для mysql код будет что-то вроде такого:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'), * 
        FROM t WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
        ORDER BY date";
$data = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP);
```

И PDO сгруппирует полученные данные по первому полю, вернув тот самый "массив с вложенными массивами, в которых будут события относящиеся к конкретному месяцу конкретного года", который и был заказан. Ключами массива будут значения вида `2016-03`, а значениями - массивы со всеми записями за указанный месяц.